# Mongoose getters and setters not functioning properly

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema, node-crypto

I'm trying to encrypt and decrypt values before and after inserting to MongoDB. I'm using mongoose schema and calling the get and set methods for encryption and decryption. The data is getting encrypted by calling set method, but while retrieving data from MongoDB it is not decrypting. Here is my schema and encryption and decryption methods:

```
var tempSchema = new Schema({    
  _id: {type: Schema.ObjectId, auto: true},
  name:{type: String},
  sample_details:{
    _id: false,
    objects: [{
      object_key:{type: String},
      object_value:{type: String, get:decrypt, set:encrypt}
    }],
    type_params:[{
      type_key:{type: String},
      type_value:{type: String, get:decrypt, set:encrypt}
    }],
    test_body:{type: String, get:decrypt, set:encrypt}
  }}, {
  toObject : {getters: true, setters: true},
  toJSON : {getters: true, setters: true}
});
```

Here are the encryption and decryption methods used:

```
function encrypt(text){
     var cipher = crypto.createCipher('aes-256-cbc', secret_key);
     var crypted = cipher.update(text,'utf8','hex');
     crypted += cipher.final('hex');
     return crypted;
}

function decrypt(text){
     if (text === null || typeof text === 'undefined') {
         return text;
     };
     var decipher = crypto.createDecipher('aes-256-cbc', secret_key);
     var dec = decipher.update(text, 'hex', 'utf8');
     dec += decipher.final('utf8');
     return dec;
}
```

Any help is appreciated, The object_value and type_value are being encrypted when saving to db, but not decrypted while retrieving from the db.

Comment: Removed my answer. Your code had no mistake, as I wrongly thought. The only way the getter's working is setting it on retrieved obj directly: `doc.toJSON({getters : true})` or `doc.toObject({getters: true})`. It should work the way you're doing. Maybe it's a bug.

Answer (score 14):

I faced similar problem and it worked for me:

1. add "using getters when converting to json" option to Schema, like :

`new mongoose.Schema({...}, {toJSON: {getters: true}})`

2. map the mongoose result to json, like:

`Products.find({}).then(a => console.log(a.map(p => p.toJSON())))`

(Description: It seems mongoose only use getters when converting to json, and its disable by default.)

Comment: I needed it in my JSON response and setting 

new mongoose.Schema({...}, {toJSON: {getters: true}

made it available.

Answer (score 2):

I've found [this issue](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/4964), which could be your problem.

If `objects` and `type_params` are passed *as objects (not arrays)*, getters work OK.

I've created snippet to test your code (hope, I've understood it correctly). `encrypt()` and `decrypt()` are simplified, since they do not matter in the question:

```
var tempSchema = new Schema({
    _id: {type: Schema.ObjectId, auto: true},
    name: {type: String},
    sample_details: {
        _id: false,
        objects: {
                object_key: {type: String},
                object_value: {type: String, get: decrypt, set: encrypt}
            },
        type_params: {
                type_key: {type: String},
                type_value: {type: String, get: decrypt, set: encrypt}
            },
        test_body: {type: String, get: decrypt, set: encrypt}
    }}, {
    toObject: {getters: true, setters: true},
    toJSON: {getters: true, setters: true},
    runSettersOnQuery: true
});


var tempModel = mongoose.model('tempmodel', tempSchema);

var dataToSave = {name: 'Name',
                  sample_details: {
                    objects: { //just an object here, no array
                            object_key: 'ObjKey',
                            object_value: 'ObjVal'
                        },
                    type_params: { //just an object here, no array
                            type_key: 'TypeKey',
                            type_value: 'TypeVal'
                        },
                    test_body: 'TestBody'
                  }
};

var doc = new tempModel(dataToSave);

doc.save().then((doc) => {
    console.log(util.inspect(doc, false, null));
    mongoose.disconnect();
});

function encrypt(text){
    return text + '_enc';
}

function decrypt(text){
    return text + '_dec';
}
```

Result in console:

```
{ sample_details:
  { objects: { object_key: 'ObjKey', object_value: 'ObjVal_enc_dec' }, //'_dec' postfix is the result of decript()
    type_params: { type_key: 'TypeKey', type_value: 'TypeVal_enc_dec' }, //'_dec' postfix is the result of decript()
    test_body: 'TestBody_enc_dec' },
  name: 'Name',
  _id: 5aaec6c2b8f0701c9476420f,
  __v: 0,
  id: '5aaec6c2b8f0701c9476420f' }
```

Comment: adding this object as second param while creating Schema worked for me:

```{
            toObject: {getters: true, setters: true},
            toJSON: {getters: true, setters: true},
            runSettersOnQuery: true
        }```